# R: RAM utilization indicated by memory.size() differs significantly from Windows Task Manager

Tags: r, windows, ram, taskmanager, memory-size

I noticed a significant difference between the RAM usage indicated by memory.size() and the RAM usage indicated in the Windows task manager. I have 8 GB of RAM.

I have a simulation where at the beginning of each period I print memory.size(). It is marked with green rectangle in the picture. RAM consumption is usually between 4GB and 7 GB with peaks going to 7949 MB.

In the Task Manager, RAM consumption is indicated much lower and never comes even close to the total built-in RAM.

Does anybody have an explanation for that? Who is wrong, R or Windows? I would think R is wrong, but unfortunately if I want to increase some parameters in my simulation, R tells me, that there is not enough memory. So finding a way to get all "real" RAM used (supposed, R handles it wrong), would be really useful.

[image: RAM usage difference between memory.size() and windows task manager]

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: Do you remove any objects before calling `memory.size()`? Have you tried calling `gc()` before `memory.size()`?

Comment: No, I don't remove any objects. I could actually do it at the beginning of each lopp, but the fundamental problem between determining the RAM utilization via R or via Windows remains, doesn't it?

Comment: The discrepancy may be between what RAM R promises to release when asked and what is free to be accessed by the system. Maybe.

Comment: R is showing you how much virtual memory - or possibly how much address space - it is using.  Task Manager is showing how much physical memory is in use.  Not the same thing.  (On the other hand, the 7.2 out of 13.1 represents total virtual memory usage, which does still suggest that R is giving up before it needs to.)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the 64-bit version of R?

Comment: I added the sessionInfo, I run RStudio 32 bit and R 64 bit. Any idea how I could make R try using all memory a little harder?